# when then otherwise in python polars

Tags: python, data-manipulation, python-polars

I have ***deneme*** named data which contains '*user_id*' and '*language*' columns. So, I want to make it categorize the language column. For example, the person with user_id is 657, wrote down ***almanca, orta...***
So this should be just ***almanca***. I wanted to do it with polars when then otherwise functions but couldnt. Here is what i tried.

I am waiting your helps.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa9Yj.png)

```
deneme.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('language').str.contains('almanca'))
    .then(deneme['language']='almanca')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("language").arr.contains("almanca")
    ).then("almanca").otherwise(None)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I did it and it works perfectly.

```
deneme = deneme.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('language').str.contains('almanca'))
    .then("german").otherwise(pl.col('language')).alias('language')
)
```